# Using wp_tag_cloud with only posts published in specific year

Tags: posts

I want to display tag clouds for specific year's posts to summarize year in post.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud has no year filter. How to get it?

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is to find the post from current year and filter out the tags from those posts. Please see the code below,

```
$getdate = getdate();
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $getdate["year"]
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$years_tag = array();

if ( $query->have_posts() ): 

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 

        $query->the_post();

        $post_tags = wp_get_post_tags( get_the_id(), array( 'fields'=>'ids' ) );

        foreach ( $post_tags as $tag) {

            if( !in_array( $tag, $years_tag ) ) {
                array_push( $years_tag, $tag );
            }
        }

    endwhile; 
endif;

$args = array(
    'include' => implode(',', $years_tag),
);

wp_tag_cloud( $args );
```

You can accurately get tags from this year **BUT** the main issue here is the count of tags is not based on this year. You can manipulate the array to bring the count along with tag ids and create your own function on that.

I hope this will be somewhat helpful to you.

Comment: include has to be a comma separated string

Comment: Oh right, i mistaken it to be an array. implode should be used to make it string